# A simple logistic regression using keras and R

Tags: keras, r, logistic-regression

I am new in ML.  I try to run a simple logistic regression using Keras in R.
I have 0 or 1 in a `train$y` data set. It corresponds to `train$x`

```
> head(train$y)
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 1
> head(train$x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   53 13.0   22
[2,]   76 17.0   14
[3,]   73 17.0   12
[4,]   67 16.0   13
[5,]   65 13.0   10
[6,]   58 16.5   17
```

Here is my code:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_flatten(input_shape = c(3)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units =1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% 
  compile(
    loss = "binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer = "rmsprop",
    metrics = "accuracy"
  )

model %>% 
  fit(
    x = mnist$train$x, y = mnist$train$y,
    epochs = 5,
    validation_split = 0.1,
    verbose = 2
  )
```

When I run prediction I receive a very different result compared to logistic regression using glm. Actually the results are almost meaningless. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happens if you increase the number of epochs? In theory, your network (which looks like it does logistic regression) should match the logistic regression, but the software might not recognize that all it has to do is find the logistic regression coefficients, instead going through the usual optimization approach that one would use for a deep network.